# Find underlying DataType (System Type) in the PropertyType.FullName using RegEx or Other possible way?

Tags: regex, reflection, nullable

I have some library that have some properties `nullable` i want to access the *underlying data type* of the property using Reflection.

> System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

How can i get they System.Int32 from RegEx??

If there any another best way to get this then it will be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really have to go via the string representation? If you've got the property itself, it's easy:

```
// This returns null if property.PropertyType isn't a Nullable<T>
Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType);
```